# d3 graph plotting issue

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I am having array of values to plot. It plots data from left to right and keep appending towards right. I would like to start the plotting again from left when the max point is reached at right side on the screen.

Could you please help.

Code Snippet

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

svg {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: brown;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var plotData=[];
   var ecgData=[];
  var cha0 = [0, 0, 1, -4, 8, -19, 35, -65, 110, -178, 276, -417, 612, -892, 1298, -1944, 3121, -5957, 32767, 32767, 32767, 18996, -23786, -32768, -32768, -4593, 32767, 32767, 32767, 32767, 21223, -12888, -32768, -32768, -32768, 755, 32767, 32767, 32767, 32767, 11486, -21409, -32768, -32768, -31892, 10839, 32767, 32767, 32767]
    var cha1 = [0, 0, 1, -4, 7, -18, 33, -61, 101, -164, 252, -379, 555, -806, 1174, -1765, 2860, -5564, 32767, 32767, 32767, 10801, -32768, -32768, -32768, -32768, 32767, 32767, 32767, 32767, 32767, -17917, -32768, -32768, -32768, -32768, 32767, 32767, 32767, 32767, 28800, -32768, -32768, -32768, -32768, -15139, 32767, 32767, 32767];
    var cha2 = [0, 0, 1, -4, 8, -19, 35, -65, 109, -177, 274, -414, 608, -886, 1290, -1931, 3102, -5927, 32767, 32767, 32767, 20743, -22528, -32768, -32768, -5018, 32767, 32767, 32767, 32767, 24725, -10077, -32768, -32768, -32768, 633, 32767, 32767, 32767, 32767, 14799, -18876, -32768, -32768, -32229, 10777, 32767, 32767, 32767];

    var chaA0 = [0, 0, 1, -4, 8, -19, 35, -65, 110, -178, 276, -417, 612, -892, 1298, -1944, 3121, -4957, 22767, 22767, 22767, 18996, -13786, -32768, -32768, -4593, 32767, 32767, 32767, 32767, 21223, -12888, -12768, -12768, -12768, 755, 12767, 12767, 22767, 22767, 11486, -21409, -22768, -22768, -21892, 10839, 22767, 22767, 22767]
    var chaA1 = [0, 0, 1, -4, 7, -18, 33, -61, 101, -164, 252, -379, 555, -806, 1174, -1765, 3860, -4564, 22767, 22767, 32767, 10801, -12768, -32768, -32768, -32768, 32767, 32767, 32767, 32767, 32767, -17917, -12768, -12768, -22768, -12768, 12767, 32767, 32767, 32767, 28800, -32768, -32768, -32768, -22768, -15139, 22767, 22767, 22767];
    var chaA2 = [0, 0, 1, -4, 8, -19, 35, -65, 109, -177, 274, -414, 608, -886, 1290, -1931, 3102, -4927, 22767, 22767, 22767, 10743, -12528, -32768, -32768, -5018, 32767, 32767, 32767, 32767, 24725, -10077, -12768, -12768, -12768, 633, 32767, 22767, 32767, 32767, 14799, -18876, -32768, -32768, -22229, 10777, 22767, 22767, 22767];
  var temp=1;
  var count = 60
  while(temp <= count) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < cha0.length; i++) {
        if(temp%2==1){
         ecgData.push(cha0[i]);

        }else{
                    ecgData.push(chaA0[i]);

        }        
  }
  temp++;
  }


    var tmp;
window.intervalId = setInterval(function () {
      tmp =0;
                if(ecgData.length>itr){

          while(tmp<50){
            if(ecgData.length>itr){
              plotData.push(ecgData[itr]);            
              itr++;
              tmp++;
            }else{
              tmp=50;
            }          
          }
        }
            }, 25);

var n = 2500;


var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 40},
    width = 1200 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, n - 1])
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([40000, -40000])
    .range([height, 0]);

var line = d3.svg.line()
    //.interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d, i) { return x(i); })
    .y(function(d, i) { return y(d); });



// Graph 1
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + y(0) + ")")
    .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"));

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left"));

var path = svg.append("g")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
  .append("path")
    .datum(plotData)
    //.data([data])
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);

tick();
var itr =0;
var flag =true
function tick() {

  path
      .attr("d", line)
      .attr("transform", null)
    .transition()
     .duration(5)
      .ease("linear")
     .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(-1) + ",0)")
      .each("start", tick);
  // redraw the line, and slide it to the left


  // pop the old data point off the front
  plotData.shift();

 // retutn callback;

}

</script>
```

Comment: I have added the code snippet. While plotting when extreme right is reached , i would like to continue plotting starting again from left.